# What's a good resource on learning OpenType?

Tags: fonts, opentype

So in my spare time I like working with fonts. During the creation process it's hard to remember all the possible features offered by OpenType at one time.

What's a good resource (maybe a primer of some sort) on using OpenType features during font creation?

Answer (score 4):

[OpenType is](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/WhatIsOpenType.mspx) a font format jointly developed by Microsoft and Adobe as an extension to Apple's TrueType font format.

And please check these links:

1. [OpenType Font language support
       table from the PDF leaflet for your
       handy reference](http://fontfeed.com/archives/opentype-fontfonts-and-the-languages-they-speak/)
2. [What is open type](http://www.fontshop.com/opentype/)
3. [OpenType Tips, Techniques,
   and Resources](http://www.senecadesign.com/designgeek/opentype.html)
4. [Beginners Guide to OpenType](http://www.magnetstudio.com/words/2010/opentype-guide)
5. [OpenType Font Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745109.aspx)

Hope they're helpful.

Comment: +1 for the link to Anne-Marie's Designgeek site. She's one of my favorite people and almost a Natural Resource in the InDesign/InCopy world. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial materials for [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) include a good introduction to opentype and a fairly comprehensive [reference table](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/GlossaryFS.html) of OTF features.